# Django annotate with aggregated average value

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

In the following example from django documentation, how to get

```
Publisher.objects.all()
```

annotated with field `average_rating` computed using average of book ratings and `max_rating` computed using maximum rating of books?

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    num_awards = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    pubdate = models.DateField()

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    registered_users = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Precisely I should be able to print something like this after the queryset:

```
for p in Publisher.objects.all().annotate(...):
    print p, p.average_rating, p.max_rating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access books of publisher using `book__rating` like this:

```
Publisher.objects.annotate(average_rating=Avg('book__rating'), max_rating=Max('book__rating'))
```

Comment: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'books_set' into field. Choices are: book, id, name, num_awards